# Characteristic curve Partial Differential Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, characteristics

I have the partial differentiation question $$du/dx -3xdu/dy = 0$$  and initial conditions $$u(x,0)=cos2x$$ I have  $$A=y+3x$$ and $$u(x,y)=B$$ from integration.

So I said $$u(x,y)=F(y+3x)$$
thus $$u(x,0)=F(3x)=cos2x$$

How would I find out what F is too sub back in or how would I do the solution? and I also would the characteristic curve be $y=y(-3x,C)$ but I have a feeling this is wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that there is a typo in $\quad\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-3x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0\quad$ and that the correct PDE is :
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-3\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$$
If not, your calculus for the characteristic $\quad A=y+3x\quad$ would be false.

With the corrected equation, I agree that the general solution is :
$$u(x,y)=F(y+3x)$$

CONDITION :

$$u(x,0)=F(3x)=\cos(2x)$$
Let $\quad X=3x\quad\implies\quad F(X)=\cos(\frac23 X)$

So, the function $F(X)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=y+3x$ :
$$u(x,y)=\cos\left(\frac23 (y+3x)\right)$$

Comment: yes it was a typo, thank you so much

Comment: How would I write the characteristic curve in the form of y=y(x,c)

Comment: $y=-3x+c$, or $y=-3x+A$ with your notation.

Comment: Hey would you please be able to take a look at another question of mine Id really appreciate it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635636/domain-solutions-on-partial-differential-equations

Comment: OK. I added a comment.