# Domain solutions on partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, characteristics

$$(1+x^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$$

integrating to give: $\arctan x=\ln y+A$

I managed to find the general solution as $u(x,y)=F(A)=F(\ln y
-\arctan x)$

I have the boundary conditions

$u(0, y) = \ln y$, for the domain $x ≥ 0, y > 0;$

$ u(x, 0) = \ln x$, for the domain $x > 0, y ≥ 0$.

I substitute the boundary conditions into the general solution, but the question asks for each of the boundary conditions, find the particular if it exist which I dont understand what to do because of the domains.

Comment: I agree with the general solution. The first boundary condition implies $F(X)=X$ and the particular solution is $u(x,y)=\ln(y)-arctan(x)$. The second boundary condition includes $y=0$ in the domain. The particular solution doesn't exists due to the not defined $\ln(0)$  (The proof isn't trivial). I suppose that just saying "no particular solution" is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u(x,y)=f(\tan^{-1}(x)-\ln y)$. The second condition $u(x,0)=\ln x$ clearly makes the problem ill posed, since $\ln y$ is not defined at $y=0$. So the solution does not exist for the second condition. The first condition $u(0,y)=\ln y$ gives $f(-\ln y)=\ln y$, ie $f(z)=-z$. This then gives $u(x,y)=\ln y-\tan^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: HI thank you for the nice explanation, was I right with my general solution as well?

Comment: yes, your general solution is correct. This is the general solution since $u=c_1$ and $\tan^{-1} x -\ln y=c_2$

Comment: Ah right thank you I thought  I made a mistake and it was  $u(x,y)=F(y/arctan(x)$